# Передать данные в скрипт из инпутов без ID

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такая функция на кнопке:

```
<a onclick="Comagic.push(['addOfflineRequest', {name: regName,  email: 'text@bkbkk.ru', phone: regPhone, message: 'text'}]);  return false" href="#fire_form_new22"  target="" data-label="Рассчитать">Рассчитать</a>
```

`regName`, `regPhone` - это, по идее, ID input-ов. 
Но форма создается в lpgenerator, и там у полей нет ID, а есть только name.

Вопрос: как мне зацепить эти input-ы?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[name='value']")...
```

или

```
document.getElementsByName("acc")[0]
```

Comment: А можете прям тут показать, как это будет выглядеть?+)

onclick="Comagic.push(['addOfflineRequest', {name: regName,  email: 'text@bkbkk.ru', phone: regPhone, message: 'text'}]);

Comment: я просмотрел что-то, что это библиотека, неправильно, наверно, я посоветовал, либо смотрите тогда API Comagic, либо напишите им в тех. поддержку, может быть, ответят